# NestJS + MikroORM EntityManager Validation Error

Tags: nestjs, grpc, mikro-orm

I started migrating a project from typeorm to MikroORM and I've been facing an issue when calling the same ( or different ) repository *more than once*. The error is as follows:

`ValidationError: Using global EntityManager instance methods for context specific actions is disallowed. If you need to work with the global instance's identity map, use 'allowGlobalContext' configuration option or 'fork()' instead.`

A more detailed explanation is:

- I am using NestJS
- DB is postgreSQL
- GRPC communication for this specific service ( not sure if that matters )
- Wrapping repository calls in rxjs observables: e.g. `from(this.userRepository.findOne({id: user.id})`

Now, I've read through the documentation and other issues here and on github mainly regarding the EntityManager and the RequestContext. I've added the `@UseRequestContext()` annotation on my controller ( and injected the private readonly orm: MikroORM, instance in the constructor ):

```js
 @GrpcMethod('UsersService', 'Login')
  @UseRequestContext()
  login(user: UserLogin): Observable<UserResponse> {
    return this.userService.login(user);
  }
```

The service itself calls userRepository.find... and via debug I can see the executed query and the result is fetched, however I have another call to the **roleRepository** later on down the line. This call fails with the error above. I've played around with it and it seems like even if I try to call the same **userRepoistory.find...** for a second time it will fail again: e.g.:

```js
loginUser(user: UserLogin) {
    return this.getUserById(user.id).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.getUserById(user.id)),
    );
  }
```

If I do the following inside the getUserById method however, it works like a charm:

```js
getUserById(id: string): Observable < User > {
    const emFork = this.em.fork();
    return from(emFork.findOne(User, {
      userId: id
    }));
```

Basically what I am trying to understand is:

- It says in the documentation that the function marked with `@UseRequestContext()` should not return anything, however when placing it on the Grpc method it works ( at least for the first repository call ). If I remove it I get the same error before calling any repositories. Am I using it correctly?
- If the forking of the EntityManager is the correct approach, wouldn't that make creating Repository classes and injecting them obsolete? Also isn't forking it each time going create a lot of instances?
- It's obvious I am lacking understanding on how this context works, so an explanation would be greatly appreciated!
- Also, any other hints/tips are welcome!

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Try swapping the order of decorators, or even have two methods calling each other (and each will have only one decorator).

Comment: @MartinAdámek thanks for the reply! I've tried both of those things with no luck. Switching the order of the decorators in the controller results in the other (caller) service not finding the implementation of the grpc ( login ) method :/

Comment: I have no idea what the other decorator does, but instead of `@UseRequestContext` you can just use `RequestContext.createAsync()` explicitly inside the method, that way it might be easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: Hi @MartinAdámek thanks for the reply! Turns out the cause of the error is actually rxjs. For some reason wrapping the promise into an observable loses the context and reverts back to the global one. As I don't have time to further investigate it now, I've decided to roll back to typeorm, as there are no issues with this there. Thanks for the help!